# How does the pH of solutions of salts in which the cation is acidic and anion basic, depend only on the relation of their constants?

Tags: analytical-chemistry, stoichiometry

My book is not very explanative about it, I'm trying to get the equation:

$$[\ce{H^+}]=\sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}\times\frac{K_\mathrm{a}}{K_\mathrm{b}}}$$

but I didn't succeed, can someone explain the theory behind and how to get the formula comparing the two ionization constants?

Translation of the actual page of the textbook (Cacace *Fondamenti di stechiometria* (in Italian)):

> Salts which cation has acid features and anions has basic features. A salt like ammonium acetate, $\ce{NH4Ac}$, release after the following (complete) dissociation:
>
> $$\ce{NH4Ac -> NH4+ +Ac-}$$
>
> A cation will behave as an acid and an anion will behave as a base.
> In cases like this one, acid-base equilibrium in solution depends only by the strength of the cation compared to the anion. It can be proved

(but it does not, that's why I'm here)

> that in first approximation , the concentration of $\ce{H+}$ in those solution is *indipendent from the concentration of the salt* and it depends only from the comparison between ionization constants of the weak acid and the weak base from which the salt has been formed:
>
> $$[\ce{H^+}] = \sqrt{K_\mathrm{w}\times\frac{K_\mathrm{a}}{K_\mathrm{b}}}$$
>
> From which:
>
> $$\mathrm{pH} = \frac{1}{2}(14 + \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{a} - \mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b})$$

It seems to be unclear. I would like to understand the mathematics of the equation that brings the comparison of the two constant became like the one I already wrote. Why is independent from the salt concentration?

Comment: I suspect this is the formula for finding the pH of the solution of the highly-soluble salt of *weak acid* and *weak base* that undergoes hydrolysis. If the question gets reopened, I'm going to post an answer with how this formula is derived.

Comment: @andselisk go ahead :D // This may be related: [Calculating pH of diprotic and amphoteric solutions](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/14553/4945)

Comment: @Martin-マーチン Thanks for reopening the question:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: as we will see later, the formula

$$[\ce{H+}] = \sqrt{\frac{K_\mathrm{w}K_\mathrm{a}}{K_\mathrm{b}}} \label{1}\tag{1}$$

is only applicable to highly soluble salts with equimolar rests of monovalent weak acid and weak base such as $\ce{NH4OAc}$, $\ce{NH4HCO3}$, $\ce{NH4HSO3}$, $\ce{NH4NO2}$ and *cannot* be used for polyvalent electrolytes, poorly soluble salts and when hydrolysis is irreversible (e.g. $\ce{Al2S3}$).

Let's derive formula \eqref{1} in for the salt of the general $\ce{BHA}$ formula. As we agreed, the salt is highly soluble (also true for your textbook example, ammonium acetate), so the main approximation here is that we assume this salt *dissociates completely* in solution:

$$\ce{BHA → BH+ + A-} \label{R1}\tag{R1}$$

Each ion participates in hydrolytic equilibrium (\eqref{R2}, \eqref{R3}), plus there is autoprotolysis of water, \eqref{R4}. Subtracting \eqref{R4} from \eqref{R2} and \eqref{R3} we get a brutto equation for hydrolysis \eqref{R5}:

$$
\begin{align}
&+\quad&\ce{BH+ + H2O &<=> B + H3O+} \label{R2}\tag{R2}\\
&+\quad&\ce{A- + H2O &<=> HA + HO-} \label{R3}\tag{R3}\\
&-\quad&\ce{2 H2O &<=>[$K_\mathrm{w}$] H3O+ + HO-} \label{R4}\tag{R4}\\
\hline
&&\ce{BH+ + A- &<=>[$K_\mathrm{h}$] B + HA}, \label{R5}\tag{R5}\\
\end{align}
$$

where $K_\mathrm{h}$ is hydrolysis constant. According to the [law of mass action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_mass_action), it can be written for \eqref{R5} as such:

$$K_\mathrm{h} = \frac{[\ce{B}][\ce{HA}]}{[\ce{BH+}][\ce{A-}]} \label{2}\tag{2}$$

Now let's multiply both divider and denominator in \eqref{2} by $[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{HO-}]$ so that

$$
\begin{align}
K_\mathrm{h} &= \left.\frac{[\ce{B}][\ce{HA}]}{[\ce{BH+}][\ce{A-}]}\qquad \right|\cdot \frac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{HO-}]}{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{HO-}]}\\
 &= \frac{\color{blue}{[\ce{B}]}\color{red}{[\ce{HA}]}[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{HO-}]}{\color{blue}{[\ce{BH+}]}\color{red}{[\ce{A-}][\ce{H3O+}]}\color{blue}{[\ce{HO-}]}}\\
 &= \frac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{HO-}]}{\color{red}{K_\mathrm{a}}\color{blue}{K_\mathrm{b}}}\\
 &= \frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a}K_\mathrm{b}}\label{3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$

where $K_\mathrm{a}$ and $K_\mathrm{b}$ are dissociation constants of the conjugated acid and conjugated base, respectively:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{HA + H2O &<=>[$K_\mathrm{a}$] A- + H3O+} \label{R6}\tag{R6}\\
\ce{B + H2O &<=>[$K_\mathrm{b}$] BH+ + HO-} \label{R7}\tag{R7}\\
\end{align}
$$

Since the dissociation of the salt is complete (see \eqref{R1}), its initial concentration $c_0$ equals to the concentrations of $\ce{BH+}$ and $\ce{A-}$ in solution:

$$c(\ce{BH+}) = c(\ce{A-}) = c_0 \label{4}\tag{4}$$

and the corresponding *equilibrium* concentrations of the ions participating in hydrolysis are

$$[\ce{BH+}] = [\ce{A-}] = (1-α)c_0, \label{5}\tag{5}$$

where $α$ is the degree of hydrolysis showing the ratio between the amount of hydrolyzed salt $n_\mathrm{h}$ to the total amount of salt $n_0$ ($α = n_\mathrm{h}/n_0$; $α\in [0;1]$). The equilibrium concentrations of the weak acid and base formed during hydrolysis are

$$[\ce{B}] = [\ce{HA}] = αc_0 \label{6}\tag{6}$$

and eq. \eqref{2} for $K_\mathrm{h}$ can be rewritten using degree of hydrolysis:

$$K_\mathrm{h} = \frac{[\ce{B}][\ce{HA}]}{[\ce{BH+}][\ce{A-}]} = \frac{α^2c_0^2}{(1-α)^2c_0^2} = \frac{α^2}{(1-α)^2} \label{7}\tag{7}$$

Note that hydrolysis constant doesn't depend on salt's concentration. Since we are interested in $\ce{pH}$, it is convenient to express $[\ce{H3O+}]$ from $K_\mathrm{a}$:

$$K_\mathrm{a} = \frac{[\ce{H3O+}][\ce{A-}]}{[\ce{HA}]};$$

$$[\ce{H3O+}] = K_\mathrm{a}\frac{[\ce{HA}]}{[\ce{A-}]} = K_\mathrm{a}\frac{αc_0}{(1-α)c_0} = K_\mathrm{a}\frac{α}{1-α} \label{8}\tag{8}$$

From \eqref{7} $α/(1-α) = \sqrt{K_\mathrm{h}}$ so that \eqref{8} finally becomes the first equation you asked about:

$$[\ce{H3O+}] = K_\mathrm{a}\sqrt{K_\mathrm{h}} = K_\mathrm{a}\sqrt{\frac{K_\mathrm{w}}{K_\mathrm{a}K_\mathrm{b}}} = \sqrt{\frac{K_\mathrm{w}K_\mathrm{a}}{K_\mathrm{b}}} \label{9}\tag{9}$$

An equation for $\mathrm{pH}$ is obtained trivially by taking negative decimal logarithm on both parts of \eqref{9}.

Comment: What's the rationale for assuming that $\alpha$ is the same in both cases?

Comment: @Zhe What do you mean? There is only one case: a single hypothetical salt (see 2nd paragraph) with its own degree of hydrolysis.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm not familiar with thinking about it this way. I was basically at the same solution as this except that I did not get to a point where the concentrations could effectively cancel to 1 because that requires an assumption that the relative concentrations of acid/conjugate acid and base/conjugate base are very close to 1. Perhaps that's the first order approximation I needed, but I didn't find a convincing reason why this should just be true.

Comment: @Zhe Oh, yes, as I mentioned, the salt must be very soluble to assume that. Otherwise you end up with a single equation with 4 variables or something. And if there also were a multi-step hydrolysis, then the math would've really gotten very wild.

Comment: I noticed that the OP's question said "to first order," so I was trying to figure out if there was an assumption we could make (aside from what you did) to basically reduce that ratio to $1 + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \ll 1$.

Comment: @Zhe Sure, one can show that for equimolar weak acid and base salts $$\frac{[\ce{H3O+}]}{[\ce{OH-}]} = \frac{K_a}{K_b},$$ express $[\ce{H3O+}]$ as $$[\ce{H3O+}]=\frac{K_aK_w}{K_b[\ce{H3O+}]}$$ from there and you arrive at the same equation. I just thought that involving degree of hydrolysis is a more elegant and general way to illustrate the derivation of that formula. Also, I didn't invent this method of calculation; it is listed in many old Soviet books on analytical and physical chemistry that I used to read when I studied chemistry (yes, they are heavy on math, too).

Comment: @andselisk Thank you for your time, it was truly clear. i'll try to make it myself and  truly understanding it. Best regards

Comment: @GabrieleSortino You are very welcome:)